# ansible throwing error on script execution

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run the script (foo) which is present under my home directory (/home/ubuntu) using ansible.

if i manually move to /home/ubuntu and run the script as below

```
./foo --arg1=aaa --arg2=xxx --arg3=yyy
```

the script is working fine in command line.

However, when i try to run the same script using ansible as below

```
- name: Running Config Script
  command: chdir=/home/ubuntu ./foo --arg1=aaa --arg2=xxx --arg3=yyy
```

The script is failing . And i also tried using script tag instead of command. Its not working .

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: You can invoke ansible-playbook using `-vvvv` flag for debugging. `/home/ubuntu/foo` is on local host or on server you are trying to provision?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested but please try using `shell` instead of `command`

```
- name: Running Config Script
  shell: ./foo --arg1=aaa --arg2=xxx --arg3=yyy
  args:
    chdir: /home/ubuntu
```